# как подключиться к Mysql?

Tags: php, laravel

Разбираюсь с фреймверком laravel 5, изучаю документацию....застрял на подключении MySQL.... прописал все в файле database.php (как внаписано в документации_):

```
  'connections' => [
      'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),      
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),      
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'forge'),        
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

так же создал,как в документации файл UserController.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Показать список всех пользователей приложения.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::select('select * from database where active = ?', [1]);

        return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
        echo $users;
    }
}
```

данные из файла .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=bukreev
DB_PASSWORD=bukreev
```

где еще надо что прописать?

Comment: Не пойму в чем вопрос... Сама база есть? К ней можно обратиться? все верно прописано? не напутано ничего? Если не конектится значит один из этих пунктов!

Comment: в файле UserController.php написан запрос....так его не выводит никуда......его нужно  подключить?

Сама база есть?                       -да,есть
К ней можно обратиться?        - что Вы имеете в виду?
все верно прописано?             - да,ошибок правописания нет
не напутано ничего?               - смотря что под этим понимать....

Comment: а если на вьюхе написать так:
`@foreach ($users as $user)
{{ $user->name }}
@endforeach`

Comment: ErrorException выдает......

Comment: я сам не ларавель гуру, но задавал ли ты настройки своей БД ещё в файле .env?

Comment: я и забыл совсем про этот файл.......спасибо,но...всеравно не подключает.......

Comment: я у себя написал то же самое и всё работает. попробуй для проверки вывести просто всех пользователей, без доп условия. Ну и если правильно всё написал в файле .env, то попробуй в database.php вместо users и root написать forge(хотя сомневаюсь что это на что-то влияет)

Comment: что-то похоже я НЕ сделал.......в database.php я все так и оставил....
в файле .env прописал:
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=bukreev
DB_PASSWORD=bukreev

Comment: UserController без изменений....он наследуется от контроллера (Controller.php)....а ГДЕ он должен вызываться(UserController)?

Comment: Во-первых, твой контроллер нужно вызвать в роутинге. При такой-то ссылке — такой-то метод с такого-то контроллера. Во-вторых, если у тебя Бд действительно называется database, а юзер приписанный к ней bukreev, тогда почему в самом начале ты писал БД users с пользователем root?

Comment: ща пересмотрю роуты,точно.....я так и думал,но спасибо огромное , что подтвердили мои догадки)))
п.с.: базы данных, пользователей,пароли я все подогнал, там все эдентично

Comment: newbie, а где еще что прописать?

Comment: прописал все в файле database.php (как внаписано в документации_): - это не нужно, если прописали данные в .env и наоборот. Советую писать все в .env

Comment: Oleg Shleif, все, вернул в файл database.php  стандартное значение forge (которое было до  этого). Где прописать соединение с UserController.php ?
я так понимаю в роутах...в папке /routes лежат файлы api.php, channels.php, console.php, web.php  ....в каком файле что прописать нужно?

Comment: web.php, совет: посмотри документацию. Все кратко описано... (Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile');)